# Does cv2 accept binary images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am facing a problem that cv2 methods like cv2.detectAndCompute, cv2.HoughlinesP fails either with depth error or NoneType when fed a binary image.
For e.g. In the following

```
def high_blue(B, G):
    if (B > 70 and abs(B-G) <= 15):
        return 255
    else:
        return 0

img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dirPath,filename))
b1 = img[:,:,0] # Gives **Blue**
b2 = img[:,:,1] # Gives Green
b3 = img[:,:,2] # Gives **Red**

zlRhmn_query = np.zeros((2400, 2400), dtype=np.uint8)
zlRhmn_query[300:2100, 300:2100] = 255
zlRhmn_query[325:2075, 325:2075] = 0

cv2.imwrite('zlRhmn_query.jpg',zlRhmn_query)

zl_Rahmen_bin = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
zl_Rahmen_bin = np.vectorize(high_blue)
zl_Rahmen_bin = zl_Rahmen_bin(b1, b2)

cv2.imwrite('zl_Rahmen_bin.jpg',zl_Rahmen_bin)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp_query, des_query = sift.detectAndCompute(zlRhmn_query,None)
kp_train, des_train = sift.detectAndCompute(zl_Rahmen_bin,None)
```

only the last line with the zl_Rahmen_bin is failing with depth mismatch error. Strangely zlRhmn_query does not throw any error.

Next, when I use the skeletonization snippet given here[http://opencvpython.blogspot.de/2012/05/skeletonization-using-opencv-python.html] and pass the skeleton to HoughLinesP, I get a lines object of type NoneType. On inspection I noticed that the skeleton array is also binary i.e. 0 or 255.

Please advise.

Comment: Looks like you aren't talking about "binary" images (in the sense that pixel is a single bit) but what would more accurately be called 8-bit grayscale using uint8 for the pixels, is that right? HoughLinesP definitely works with grayscale using 0/255, chances are that it isn't finding any lines in your image with the parameters you are providing to HoughLinesP. My personal experience of using python opencv is that it's a good idea to name all the optional parameters, like `rawlines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cdst, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=50, minLineLength=50, maxLineGap=20)`

Comment: @barny in image-processing binary image always refers to an image that only has 2 different values. data type and the actual values don't matter. although that may sound confusing to some programmers :)

Comment: @Piglet Whatever. Anyway HoughLinesP definitely works with grayscale binary image - most likely reason for empty results is nothing found, due to combination of the image and the parameters.

Comment: @barny you were right. The problem was in the parameters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have programmed like 50 lines of Python in my life so excuse me if I am mistaken here.

```
zl_Rahmen_bin = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
```

you have just created a 2d array filled with zeros.

```
zl_Rahmen_bin = np.vectorize(high_blue)
```

now you immediately assign another value (a function) to the same variable, which makes the first line pretty obsolete.

```
zl_Rahmen_bin = zl_Rahmen_bin(b1, b2)
```

So as far as I understand it you just called a function z1_Rahmen_bin and provided the blue and green image as input. The output should be another 2d array with values either 0 or 255.

I was wondering how np.vectorize knows which datatype the output should be. As you obviously need uint8. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) says that the type, if not given is determined by calling the function with the first argument. So I guess the default type of 255 or 0 in this example.

and z1_Rahmen_bin.dtype actually is np.uint32.

So I modified this:

```
zl_Rahmen_bin = np.vectorize(high_blue)
```

To

```
zl_Rahmen_bin = np.vectorize(high_blue, otypes=[np.uint8])
```

which seems to do the job.

Maybe it is sufficient to just do

```
z1_Rahmen_bin.dtype = np.uint8
```

But as I said I have no idea about Python...

Comment: @AvishekDutta I just made a wild guess and printed it :) `print(zl_Rahmen_bin.dtype)`